# Book Problem Probability

Tags: probability

A shelf has 2 math books and 3 physics books. Two of the books are selected at random. Let X be the number of math books in the sample. Construct a probability table for X. Find E(X) using the table.

$$P(X=j)=\binom{5}{2}(2/5)^{j}(3/5)^{j-1}$$
$$P(X=2)=\binom{5}{2}(2/5)^{2}(3/5)^{0}=0.16$$
$$P(X=1)=\binom{5}{2}(2/5)^{1}(3/5)^{1}=0.48$$
$$P(X=0)=\binom{5}{2}(2/5)^{0}(3/5)^{2}=0.36$$

$$E(X)=np$$

I don't really understand what E(x) is/how to compute it?

Comment: Tip: this is *not* a **binomial distribution**.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathsf E[X]$ is the expectation of the random variable.  Also known as the mean.  For discrete random variables it's the sum of the product of all values of the variable and their probabilities.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E[X] &= \sum_{x=0}^2 x\mathsf P(X=x) 
\\ & = 0 \times \mathsf P(X=0)+1\times \mathsf P(X=1)+2\times \mathsf P(X=2)
\\ & = \ldots
\end{align}$$

Substitute the values from the table and evaluate.

---

Note however that probability formula you have is incorrect.

When choosing $2$ of $5$ books( $2$ maths and $3$ physics), then the probability of choosing $X$ maths books, for $x\in \{0,1,2\}$ is:

$$\mathsf P(X=x) = \frac{{2\choose x}{3\choose 2-x}}{{5\choose 2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

One can think of the expected value as the "average" of the outcome when the event is performed a large number of times. It is computed by taking the sum (if $X$ is discrete, in this case it is) over all the possible values of $X$ multiplied by the probability $X$ achieves the said value. In other words, it's a weighted average between the possible outcomes of $X$.

In this example,

$\mathbb{E}X = \sum_n nP(X=n) = 0\cdot P(X=0) + 1 \cdot P(X=1) + 2 \cdot P(X=2) = 0 + 0.48 + 0.32 = 0.8$.