# Book Problem E(X) and Probability Table

Tags: probability

A shelf has 2 math books and 3 physics books. Two of the books are selected at random. Let X be the number of math books in the sample. Construct a probability table for X. Find E(X) using the table.

$$P(X=j)=\binom{5}{2}(2/5)^{j}(3/5)^{j-1}$$
$$P(X=2)=\binom{5}{2}(2/5)^{2}(3/5)^{0}=0.16$$
$$P(X=1)=\binom{5}{2}(2/5)^{1}(3/5)^{1}=0.48$$
$$P(X=0)=\binom{5}{2}(2/5)^{0}(3/5)^{2}=0.36$$

$$E(X)=np$$

I don't really understand what E(x) is/how to compute it?

Comment: The exact same problem with two valid answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955072/book-problem-probability/955111#955111

Comment: I think you are intended to take two books from the shelf *without replacement*. You solved the "with replacement" problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book Problem Probability](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955072/book-problem-probability)

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine, that you take one book after another. Let´s calculate $P(X=0)$.

$P(Y_i=1)$: Probability, that the ith book is a physics book.

Probability, that the first book is a physics book: $P(Y_1=1)=\frac{3}{5}$

There are only 4 books left. Two of them are physics books.

Probability, that the second book is a physics book, given that the first book is a physics book: $P(Y_2=1|Y_1=1)=\frac{2}{4}$

The probability, that the first book and the second book are physics books is:

$P(Y_1=1 \cap Y_2=1)= P(Y_1=1) \cdot P(Y_2=1|Y_1=1)=\frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{2}{4}=P(X=0)$